# data types error - program to find the union of two arrays (c)

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a program in C to create a union between two arrays, then output the total number of elements in the new array.  I am getting the following errors when compiling my code (gcc).

test.c:44:11: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
 void union(int arrA[], int arrB[], int m, int n)
           ^
test.c:44:6: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 void union(int arrA[], int arrB[], int m, int n)
      ^

I've checked through for missing semicolons, etc.  So unless I'm just missing it, I can't figure out where the issue is coming from.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        int n;
        int m;
        int i;
        int k;
        printf("Enter the size of array A: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int arrA[n];
        printf("Enter the element(s) of array A: ");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {   
                scanf("%d",&arrA[i]);
            }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                printf("%d",arrA[i]);
            }
        printf("\n");

        printf("Enter the size of array B: ");
        scanf("%d",&m);
        int arrB[m];
        printf("Enter the element(s) of array B: ");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&arrB[i]);
            }
        for(i=0; i<m; i++)
            {
        printf("%d",arrB[i]);
            }
        printf("\n");

        printf("%d\n",k);
        return 0;
    }


    int union(int arrA[], int arrB[], int m, int n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int l = 0;
        if(n > m)
            {
                n = l;
            }
        else
            {
                m = l;
            }
        int arrC[l];
        while ((i < n) && (j < m))
        {
            if (arrA[i] < arrB[j])
            {
                arrC[k] = arrA[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            else if (arrA[i] > arbB[j])
            {
                arrC[k] = arrB[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                arrC[k] = arrA[i];
                i++;
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        if (i == n)
        {
            while (j < m)
            {
                arrC[k] = arrB[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (i < n)
            {
                arrC[k] = arrA[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        return(k);
    }
```

Comment: I can't check it right now, but the problem is probably caused by the name of the function. Union is a reserved word. Try renaming your function to, e.g., array_union.

Comment: you cannot call a function `union` as it is a reserved word for the C language.

Comment: thanks - didn't realize union was a reserved word!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by sawims in the comments, union is a reserved word and you had a typo on `else if (arrA[i] > arbB[j])`, changing the function's name and fixing the typo your code compiles.

http://ideone.com/ubB1eG